# How to generate the proper `url_for` a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, named-routing

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to generate a proper `url_for` URL for a nested resource. That is, I have:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :user_associations
end

# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# app/models/articles/user_association.rb
class Articles::UserAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

*Note*: generated named routes are like `article_user_associations`, `article_user_association`, `edit_article_user_association`, ...

When in my view I use:

```
url_for([@article, @article_association])
```

Then I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `article_articles_user_association_path' for #<#<Class:0x000...>
```

However, if I state routers this way

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :user_associations, :as => :articles_user_associations
end
```

the `url_for` method works as expected and it generates, for instance, the URL `/articles/1/user_associations/1`.

*Note*: in this case, generated named routes are like `article_articles_user_associations`, `article_articles_user_association`, `edit_article_articles_user_association`, ...

However, I think it isn't "good" the way routers are builded / named in the latter / working case. So, **is it possible in some way to make the `url_for` method to work by generating named routes like `article_user_association` (and not like `article_articles_user_association`)?**

---

I read the [Official Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) related to the `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`  method (in particular the "URL generation for named routes" section), but I cannot find out a solution. Maybe there is a way to "say" to Rails to use a specific named router as-like it makes when you want to change the primary key column of a table with the `self.primary_key` statement...

```
# app/models/articles/user_association.rb
class Articles::UserAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # self.primary_key = 'a_column_name'
  self.named_router = 'user_association'

  ...
end
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a naming conflict with the "associations" somehow... it just seems to strike a memory of seeing a "model_associations" somewhere.

Comment: @DGM - I don't know that, but I think it is a common issue where many people stumble.

Comment: nope, I missed the namespace thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserAssociation` model is in the `Articles` namespace, which gets included in the named route:

```
# app/models/articles/user_association.rb
class Articles::UserAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

#        route =>           articles_user_association
# nested route =>   article_articles_user_association
```

If you remove the namespace, you will get the route helper you are looking for:

```
# app/models/articles/user_association.rb
class UserAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

#        route =>           user_association
# nested route =>   article_user_association
```

Unless you have a really good reason for keeping `UserAssociation` in a namespace, don't.

Comment: I know that if I remove the namespace I will get the route helper I am looking for, but the reason is that I have a lot of models and, in order to keep all them in an easy "fashion", I locate/store them in sub-directories under the `app/models` directory and so I must namespace those.