# Rails form_for as: with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I've got routes setup like the following:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :project_factors, as: factors
end
```

I like having the `as: :factors` so the route becomes:

```
project_factor_path(@project, @project_factor)
```

instead of

```
project_project_factor_path(@project, @project_factor)
```

but I'm having trouble getting `form_for` to generate the correct route.

`form_for [@project, @project_factor]` fails (as expected) because it tries to use `project_project_factor_path`, so I tried:

```
form_for [@project, @project_factor], as: :factor
```

but this fails with exactly the same error.

Is there a way to get rails to generate the correct path here without explicitly setting the correct `url` parameter for the create and update case?

Comment: This previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906793/how-to-generate-the-proper-url-for-a-nested-resource seems to indicate that if you're using a namespace on the classname it might be interfering with auto-generating your route from the object... have you named your project factors class something like: `Project::ProjectFactor` ???

Comment: No, just named ProjectFactor: `class ProjectFactor < Factor`

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but you can pass in the path separately to the objects eg something like:

```
form_for [@project, @project_factor], :url => project_factor_path(@project, @project_factor)
```

(Note: not tested)

It feels a bit redundant to me though... which is exactly what you were trying to reduce, so probably not a good solution for you :P

An alternative might be just to rename your `project_factor` model to `factor`. You can still give the database table name as `project_factors` (use `self.table_name = 'project_factors'` in the class for Rails to find it).

To me, `project/project_factors` feels a bit like smurf-typing... ;)
YMMV

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned, explicitly setting the url is what I'm trying to avoid since then I have to have a condition on the form for if the record is saved or not.

Renaming the model isn't really an option here, ProjectFactor already inherits from Factor. My question is really why `as` in form_for is having no effect on the generated url.

Comment: yeah... and I agree it's a good question (to which I do not know the answer)... might be worth delving into the source code for `url_for` (though it's likely to be a rabbit warren)